# Why do I get this Python script execution error? - ccxt binance code is working well on Windows, but running error on Ubuntu, Google Cloud

Tags: python-3.x, cloud, trading, binance, ccxt

It is a strange phenomenon.

`The code works normally on Windows (PC), but an error message occurs in Google Cloud as well as AWS, Azure`

Given the following code:

```
import ccxt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

# binance keys
API_KEY = ''
SECRET_KEY = ''

# binance API
exchange = ccxt.binance()
exchange.apiKey = API_KEY
exchange.secret = SECRET_KEY
exchange.options = {'defaultType': 'future', 'adjustForTimeDifference': True, 'recvWindow' : 10000,'defaultTimeInForce': 'GTC', 'timeDifference': 0}


coin_lists = ['REN/USDT', 'ZIL/USDT', 'CELR/USDT', 'TRX/USDT', 'VET/USDT', 'RVN/USDT','ARPA/USDT','ANKR/USDT','IOTX/USDT','XEM/USDT', '1000XEC/USDT']


# ticker's price
def cur_price(symbol):
    ohlc = exchange.fetchOHLCV(symbol=symbol, timeframe='5m', limit=1)
    return ohlc[0][4]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # test code
    balance = exchange.fetch_balance()
    df_1 = DataFrame(balance)

    # main code
    pool = mp.Pool(processes =None)
    ticker_price = list(pool.map(cur_price, coin_lists))
    print(ticker_price)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

**My environment :**
**Desktop:** window10, vscode

**Google Cloud:** Ubuntu 21.10

**Python :** 3.8.12 64-bit

Phenomenon:
The executable code below works normally on Windows (PC). However, errors occur in the clouds service such as Google Cloud Platform with ubuntu.

`The code in question(Part of doubt):`
If you comment out the #test code part, it works normally on Windows and Goodle Cloud.
An error occurs only when ‘balance = exchange.fetch_balance()’ is with the #main code part below.
But on Windows it works just fine anyway.

This code is absolutely necessary to check the balance.

`Please help me!!!`

**Error Message**

```
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1371, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 319, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 288, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 532, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 718, in reraise

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
exchange.apiKey = API_KEY
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/home/g0xdroneart/auto_trading/t.py", line 26, in cur_price
    ohlc = exchange.fetchOHLCV(symbol=symbol, timeframe='5m', limit=1)
  File "/home/g0xdroneart/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ccxt/binance.py", line 1887, in fetch_ohlcv
    response = getattr(self, method)(self.extend(request, params))
  File "/home/g0xdroneart/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py", line 457, in inner
    return entry(_self, **inner_kwargs)
  File "/home/g0xdroneart/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ccxt/binance.py", line 4401, in request
    response = self.fetch2(path, api, method, params, headers, body, config, context)
  File "/home/g0xdroneart/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py", line 502, in fetch2
    return self.fetch(request['url'], request['method'], request['headers'], request['body'])
  File "/home/g0xdroneart/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py", line 639, in fetch
    raise NetworkError(details) from e
ccxt.base.errors.NetworkError: binance GET https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/klines?interval=5m&limit=1&sym
bol=CELRUSDT
"""
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/g0xdroneart/auto_trading/t.py", line 37, in <module>
    ticker_price = list(pool.map(cur_price, coin_lists))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
ccxt.base.errors.NetworkError: binance GET https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/klines?interval=5m&limit=1&sym
bol=CELRUSDT
```

Comment: Are you sure that your cloud instances have network access? You could try running a simple `urllib.request`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#examples

Comment: Absolutely sure

Comment: Even on google cloud, it is working wery well  without #test code part.

Comment: the "test code" makes a network connection so that's where the problem comes from

Comment: There is no problem on window(PC) but I got a error on Google Cloud. 
I doubt it happens between multiprocessing function and API call just on Google cloud.